# Input data returns undefined after adding the 11th row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I've been working on a table where I need to copy the previous data to the new row on either enter key click or button click. It's working as expected except the data becomes undefined once it reached to the 11th row.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
// GET ID OF last row and increment it by one
var $lastChar = 1, $newRow;
$get_lastID = function(){
    var $id = $('#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id");

    var prev_char = $lastChar = parseInt($('#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id").slice(-1));
    var courier_name = $('#courier_name_'+prev_char).val();
    var vendor_name = $('#vendor_name_'+prev_char).val();

    //console.log('GET id: ' + $lastChar + ' | $id :'+$id);
    $lastChar = $lastChar + 1;
    $newRow = "<tr> \
                <td><input type='text' class='form-control input-sm track_no' name='courier_tracking_no[]' id='courier_tracking_no_"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                <td><input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' name='courier_name[]' id='courier_name_"+$lastChar+"' value='"+courier_name+"'/></td> \
                <td><input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' name='vendor_name[]' id='vendor_name_"+$lastChar+"' value='"+vendor_name+"' /></td> \
                <td class='box-action'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs del_ExpenseRow'><span class='fui-cross'></span></button></td> \
            </tr>";
    return $newRow;
}

$('#receiving-box-table').on('keypress','input[name^="courier_tracking_no[]"]:last',function(e){
    console.log(this);
    $get_lastID();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#receiving-box-table tbody').append($newRow);
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input.track_no').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});


// ***** -- START ADDING NEW ROWS
$('#add_ExpenseRow').on("click", function(){
    $get_lastID();
    $('#receiving-box-table tbody').append($newRow);
});

$('#receiving-box-table').on('click','tr .del_ExpenseRow',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $lastChar = $lastChar-1;
  });

});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="receiving-box-table" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Courier Tracking #</th>
                        <th>Courier</th>
                        <th>Vendor</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm track_no" name="courier_tracking_no[]" id="courier_tracking_no_1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="courier_name[]" id="courier_name_1" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="vendor_name[]" id="vendor_name_1" /></td>
                        <td class="box-action"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs clear-data"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="text-right">
                <button id="add_ExpenseRow" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Add</button> <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My guess is, this code is the culprit:

```
var prev_char = $lastChar = parseInt($('#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id").slice(-1));
```

since after it reaches **10**, it goes back to **1**. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
  var str = $('#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id");

  var index = str.lastIndexOf("_");
var result = str.substr(index+1);
  console.log(result)

   var prev_char = $lastChar = parseInt(result);
```

Codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EXgqOz

**Issue:** For variables prev_char,$lastChar .slice(-1) will return only last string i.e 0 for courier_name_1**0** instead of last 2 strings i.e 10

**Resolution:** Instead of slice(-1) , use lastIndexOf for getting strings after last underscore

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you very much @Naga Sai A :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like prev_char is getting sliced from the right resulting to 0 when it is 10.

You can find the substring in your ID and replace it with blank to get the number:

```
var str = $('#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id");
var prev_char = parseInt(str.replace("courier_tracking_no_", ""));
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but I think this will work, too. Thanks @Rad Apdal!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your answer with a little modification.

```
    if ($('#receiving-box-table tr').length <= 10){
        var prev_char = $lastChar = parseInt($('#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id").slice(-1));
    } else {
        var prev_char = $lastChar = parseInt($('#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id").slice(-2));
    }
```

This would resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sSaroj! That will work as well but what if it reaches to a hundred or thousand rows? I'd like my code to be flexible.